# Detect user activity in Cocoa app (taps, clicks, ...)

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa

For a Mac application, I want to detect user activity in the app, so I can periodically let a web service know that the user is still active on the endpoint.

In Cocoa Touch, I would override `sendEvent` of `UIApplication`, but the `sendEvent` in `NSApplication` equivalent in Cocoa, doesn't do the same.

Which APIs should I use instead for a Mac application, to detect user activity? Can I perhaps somehow have a global responder hookup from where I can send the pings to my service?

Preferably, I want to listen for actions the user can be expected to perform every 15-30 second, ie. clicks, tabs, typing, switching windows or applications.

Comment: If you need access to *every* event, override `- nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:` and react to the event pump.

Comment: Hmm, tried to override it, and stuck a breakpoint in it. Not getting hit at all. Any gotcha's?

Comment: Now that doesn't make any sense unless your class isn't actually being instantiated.  That method is the one-and-only event pump in AppKit.

Comment: That might be because I override the Principal class with my own Swift class (even if it inherits from NSApplication)

Comment: Have you fully qualified the name you gave to NSPrincipalClass in your plist?  It's possible you're missing a module name and AppKit is working around you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely want to create a [global event monitor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MonitoringEvents/MonitoringEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH15-SW3) using [`+[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:). This calls your handler whenever an event whose type matches the passed mask (you should use `NSAnyEventMask`) is sent to another application. You can observe, but not change, the event here, which suits your usage perfectly. There is one thing to watch out for: the documentation says that you won't receive key events unless your app is trusted for Accessibility.

You can do similarly for events that are routed to your own application with [`+[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:).

Comment: for me, the `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` worked best (the other one doesn't seem to work)

Answer (score 4):

It's not a notification, but you can query the time since user activity using `CGEventSourceSecondsSinceLastEventType(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState, kCGAnyInputEventType)`.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
-(void) addMyApplicationEventsMonitor {
    self.localEventsMonitor = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSEventMaskAny handler:^NSEvent * (NSEvent *  event) {
        // do your stuff here
        return event;
    }];
}

-(void)dealloc{
    //remember add this to remove your monitor
    [NSEvent removeMonitor:self.localEventsMonitor];
}
```

[reference here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1534971-addlocalmonitorforevents)